# How working with fields out from DetailsView

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

I'm newbie in ASP.Net C#.

I made a site on Classic ASP, but I need to recreate on .NET. I am using DetailsView on detail page.

I need to move some fields to another place on mi page. Example: usually put the name on page top, email place is on top too but right side inside a DIV formatted with bootstrap.

I don't know how separate fields that are grouped on DetailsViews's table.

All information on MS site talks about DetailsView, this stuff it's cool but I want more flexibility for placing fields anywhere. DetailsView's table makes me feel tied.

Comment: You can show detail view code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the section of your code your trying to change? May be easier to understand your question.

Comment: here is my code  in two parts: <div class="panel-body">
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="lct_caso" DataSourceID="sqlDS_detalleCaso" Height="50px"  Width="125px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
<CommandRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" />
<EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
 <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#E9ECF1" Font-Bold="True" />
<Fields>

Comment: <asp:BoundField DataField="responsable_registro" HeaderText="responsable_registro" SortExpression="responsable_registro" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="editor_agencia" HeaderText="editor_agencia" 
 SortExpression="editor_agencia" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="editor_nombre" HeaderText="editor_nombre" 
 ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="editor_nombre" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="siglas" HeaderText="siglas" ReadOnly="True" 
SortExpression="siglas" />

Comment: ok, that was a part of my code, i want to place "responsable_registro" and "editor_agencia" in another place, not in detailsview table. is it possible? in asp classic this is possible by calling fields from a recordset. is it any equivalence in asp.net?

Comment: Can you please give an example of how you can do this in classic ASP?